# Removing Out Of Sync MYSQL Slaves

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, master-slave

I have a MYSQL master-slave setup with 4 slaves. It doesn't happen often but slaves can go out of sync causing errors in the application on critical reads. Application side this seems messy to fix, is there a good load balancing option that can automatically remove slaves if they go out of sync?

Comment: Just curious...how do they go out of sync? I don't see anything messy in fixing this. When there's something messy about it, you're doing something wrong in my opinion.

Comment: In reality the solution is to move to a cluster. If you have a long query running on the slave is when it can get out of sync by 5-10 mins

Comment: I don't see how a long running query will get the slave out of sync. There may be something seriously wrong with your setup. Just to clarify, you're not writing on your slaves, aren't you? Maybe you should explain your whole setup and use case. Beware of the [xy-problem!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;)

Comment: Ok, questions to be asked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool but this can be simple if you write a shell script to  check slave status and if it is not in sync then stop service. if you need help in that please let me know.